# Managing Access with Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, sharing

I'm currently working on a document creation/approval space for my employer. Documents are drafted in Sharepoint Online within a library that has restricted access, but individual items are to be shared more broadly with potential collaborators using sharing links. Eventually, the document's owner can trigger a publication process, which uses Microsoft Flow.

The current thinking from a design perspective is that the original file will remain in place when the file is published - however, the project directors would prefer it if the contributors automatically lost their permissions at this point. Is there a way to delete those in the same flow?

I've considered copying the file and deleting the original but this seems inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported OOB with Flow at this point, though it is possible. This [blog post](https://noellawlor.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/setting-sharepoint-item-list-permissions-with-flow/) goes through the procedure of using the REST API from within flow to break permission inheritance and set permissions.

As an alternative, reconfigure a SharePoint workflow using SharePoint Designer to handle the permissions management. The 2010 workflow engine has the actions, and it only takes minutes to set up.